# What is it called when organizations set stations (tables and stuff) to deliver information?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'd like to know what those information stations (just like tea/coffee stations) are called?

Comment: If they are transitory, they are sometimes called pop-ups, at least here in London, UK.

Comment: They used to call it a 'bureau,' and now it's called a 'kiosk,' 'booth' or sometimes even 'station' as you suggested. I am far more familiar with 'help desk' than other alternates.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it a information kiosk or a helpdesk

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a business convention or trade show, such a display can be called a **booth** or *trade show booth*.  These may just be tables with pamphlets or fliers, etc., but they are often more elaborate displays with back-drops, video displays, and other things to catch the attention of show attendees.

[image: Illustration from Wikipedia]

Comment: A 'booth' is usually closed on some or all sides. A 'kiosk' is open, and may even be just a desk or 'bureau.' Today, though, the terms 'kiosk' and 'booth' are used almost interchangeably and 'bureau' has passed into history.